# How does Zero Knowledge Encryption (User-Controlled End-to-End Encryption) work?

Tags: security, encryption

mega.nz has a security key. We need it to recover the account. They say that If we lose this Recovery key and also forget the password then all our files, folders and messages will be inaccessible, even by MEGA.

[image]

In their [feature page](https://mega.nz/security), they call it "Zero Knowledge Encryption (User-Controlled End-to-End Encryption)". It says:

> All your data on MEGA is encrypted with a key derived from your
> password; in other words, your password is your root encryption key.
> MEGA does not have access to your password or your data. Using a
> strong and unique password will ensure that your data is protected
> from being hacked and gives you total confidence that your information
> will remain just that – yours.

In a [blog post](https://help.mega.nz/webclient/security-and-privacy.html#how-does-the-encryption-work) they also said:

> The client machines are responsible for generating, exchanging and
> managing the encryption keys. MEGA's encryption model does not require
> any usable symmetric or private keys to ever leave the end-user's
> computer.

What do I need to do to implement such a system where I do not have access to user password or data.

Comment: Just like they say. The client computer (mobile app, or browser or whatever) stores PBKDF2 with enough derivations that they can then use it for something like AES. I would guess that the 'recovery key' is the actual PBKDF2 password used for AES so if you forget what your password was, you at least have encryption key to re-encrypt all your files. Which is also why you should keep this stuff secret.

Comment: @zaitsman this gives hint to the solution. Now I have to go and search for "PBKDF2 with enough derivations" & "PBKDF2 password".