# What is "Privacy by Design"? And how to achieve it?

Tags: privacy

I noticed that tutanota and mega.io mentioned "Privacy by design" in their homepages. So, I became curious and found the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_by_design) page about Privacy by design, but it seems to be an abstract concept (a collection of principals). However, I was looking for something like - do a and b or implement y and z. For example, mega.io uses [Zero Knowledge Encryption (User-Controlled End-to-End Encryption)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68310184/how-does-zero-knowledge-encryption-user-controlled-end-to-end-encryption-work). What other features do a product need to have to be called a "Privacy by Design" service.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a specific programming question. You may have better luck posting on [security.se] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By their very nature, abstract principles do not concern themselves with implementation detail. There are many different ways to implement them, and mandating one approach over another is simply out of scope – what matters is the net effect. It's also applicable to non-tech environments, paper records, etc; it's not exclusive to web dev.

Privacy by design (PbD) is a term coined by Ann Cavoukian, an ex-information commissioner in Canada, and it has a collection of principles, as that Wikipedia page describes. PbD is also [referenced by GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/issues/privacy-by-design/). I've given various talks on privacy and security at tech conferences around the world – you can see [one of my slide decks on PbD](https://speakerdeck.com/synchro/understanding-privacy-by-design-confoo-2020).

So how do you use them in web development? Take the second principle: "Privacy as the default". This means that if a person using your web app does nothing special, their privacy must preserved. This means, amongst other things, that you should not load any tracking scripts (perhaps even remote content), and not set any cookies that are not strictly necessary. If you *do* want to track them (and thus break the user's privacy to some extent), then you need to take actual laws into account, such as the EU privacy directive, which is what requires consent for cookies and trackers.

So although the principle itself did not require these measures, it influenced the technical decisions you needed to make in your implementation in order to comply with the spirit of the principle. If that happens, the principle has done its job.

So what you have to do in order to claim privacy by design (though it's not like you get a badge!) is to introspect and consider how these principles apply to your own services, then act on those observations and make sure that the things you design and build conform to the principles. This is a difficult process (especially at first), but there are tools to help you perform "privacy impact assessments" (also [part of GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/issues/privacy-impact-assessment/)) such as the excellent [PIA](https://www.cnil.fr/en/open-source-pia-software-helps-carry-out-data-protection-impact-assesment) tool by the French information commissioner (CNIL).

If you're thinking about PbD, it's worth looking at two other important lists: [the data protection principles](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-5-gdpr/) that have been the basis of pretty much all European legislation since the 1980s, including GDPR, and the [6 bases for processing in GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-6-gdpr/). If you get your head around these three sets of concerns, you'll have a pretty good background on how you might choose to implement something privacy-preserving, and also a good set of critical guidelines that will help you to spot privacy flaws in products and services. A great example of this is Google Tag Manager; it's a privacy train wreck, but I'll leave it to you to contemplate why!

Minor note: the GDPR links I have provided are not to [the official text of GDPR](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32016R0679), but a reformatted version that is much easier to use.